# Cannot access site - IE TLS error, Chrome ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, internet-explorer

Access to a web application for certain users (not all), at certain times (not always) results in the following error

In IE:

> This page can’t be displayed  Turn on TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, and TLS 1.2 in
>   Advanced settings and try connecting to https://SITEADDRESS again. If
>   this error persists, it is possible that this site uses an unsupported
>   protocol or cipher suite such as RC4 (link for the details), which is
>   not considered secure. Please contact your site administrator.

In Chrome, I get a ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

F12> Network tab shows no activity when trying to access the site.

Any ideas on what might be the issue and how to address it. The web application is built on Angularjs and is running on IIS

Comment: The issue was the gateway that we were using for our VPN to Microsoft Azure. Upgraded that to Express Route and the issue went away

Answer (score 0):

The issue in this case was the gateway that we were using for our VPN to Microsoft Azure. Upgraded that to Express Route and the issue went away